# Specifiying TD class for newly inserted row in JQUERY datatable

Tags: jquery, datatables

I've a Table which is being rendered using JQUERY Datatable plugin. Am trying to add new rows to the table via this code

```
var oTable = $('#table_question').DataTable();
oTable.row.add(['', '', '']);
```

But when the new row getting inserted, its not having any classes for each of the TD in rows abouve it. So I need to add class **col-1** to first column and **col-2** to second column. How can I specify this classes when at the time of adding itself? Also how can I give any specific template to each of the cell while at the time of adding new rows via **row.add**

Answer (score 10, accepted):

To add different classes to different columns / `<td>`'s in a newly added row, access each `<td>` as jQuery instances by `column(<index>).nodes().to$()` :

```
var row = table.row.add(['someValue', 'someOtherValue']);
table.row(row).column(0).nodes().to$().addClass('testClass1');
table.row(row).column(1).nodes().to$().addClass('testClass2');
table.row(row).draw();
```

demo with a button and a popup where the user can add new rows on the fly, and different CSS classes is added to each `<td>` -> **http://jsfiddle.net/3vp55tgh/**

Comment: Thanks pal.. Thats perfect

Comment: But this is very slow, if data there are thousands rows and they come via AJAX...

Comment: @Boolean_Type, agree, but if you have thousands of rows you are using `serverSide` anyway

Answer (score 1):

Cache your newly added `row` and `addClass` normally as below:

```
var oTable = $('#table_question').DataTable();
var rowNode = oTable.row.add(['', '', '']);
$( rowNode ).addClass('anyclass');
```

Here are the Docs while adding <kbd>**[single row](https://datatables.net/reference/api/row.add())**</kbd> and for <kbd>**[multiple rows](https://datatables.net/reference/api/rows.add())**</kbd>

Comment: Are you sure $(rowNode).addClass will work since its the datatable API instance only with the new row in its result set.

Comment: Yea.. I tried it... But addClass wont work since its (rownode) only the datatable object and not the TD

Comment: Sorry.. I didnt used node method. But I use draw(false)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/92022/discussion-between-sforsandeep-and-guruprasad-rao).

Comment: You should never try to manipulate the content of a dataTable instance beyond the dataTables API.

Comment: @davidkonrad.. Thanks for the info.. But as I read from the docs, it was mentioned that we can change `css` as well as `animate` for the `rownode` which made me to think that `adding class` wouldn't be offensive. Can you also please tell what is that `.to$()` in your answer.. Is it `dataTables` method?

Comment: hey @GuruprasadRao, but it causes serious errors -> **http://jsfiddle.net/8vykd8pk/** [and jQuery errors, not "just" dataTables errors, so it is really bad :-)] I believe the documentation simply is wrong for that part. [**to$()**](https://datatables.net/reference/api/to%24()) or `toJQuery()` gives you access to the actual element stored in dataTables internals as a jQuery instance.

Comment: @davidkonrad I believe `docs` are correct because they have specifically shown in the example to access the rows after using `.draw()` and `.node()` to fetch the added `row` and they use `jquery` functions.. :) Here is your **[`updated fiddle`](http://jsfiddle.net/Guruprasad_Rao/8vykd8pk/1/)** ..Anyways.. I wasn't aware of `to$` though.. Thanks for that,, :)

Answer (score 1):

Accepted solution works very slow, if there are thousands rows and they come via AJAX (in my case it was custom AJAX realization: first 50 rows came from the server and next rows parts were loaded in a loop – 50 in every batch).

The following solution was helpful for me:

```
var table = $('#tableID').DataTable({
    'createdRow': function (row, data, dataIndex) {
         //no jQuery, just native JS to ensure fast
         row.children[0].classList.add("col-md-1");
         row.children[1].classList.add("col-md-3");
         row.children[2].classList.add("col-md-2");
     }
});
```

Comment: I agree, using jQuery is a ridiculous bottleneck. But if you have this exact need, why not use [**className**](https://datatables.net/reference/option/columns.className) in the `columns` or `columnDefs` definition anyway?

Comment: @davidkonrad , yeah, you are right. This solution is fast to.